# Can't handle browser window (htmlunit)

Tags: browser, htmlunit

I want to download **config.bin** file from site. Work with htmlunit

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(2000);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

webClient.setConfirmHandler(new ConfirmHandler() {
    public boolean handleConfirm(Page page, String message) {
        System.out.println(" -----------------------");
        System.out.println("handle config");
        System.out.println(" -----------------------");
        return true;
    }
});
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://site");
final DomElement backup = mainFrame.getElementByName("Backup");
        webClient.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener()
        {
            public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1");
            };

            public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent
                                                        event)
            {
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!2");
            }

            public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!3");
            }
        });

        InputStream input = backup.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

Then submited `ckick()` I think that get stream,  but got submit page. I think that I have problem with browser window and I can't handle browser window. I insert `sout` in handler and see when  this method to called but it didn't call   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in period that i install. changed `setTimeout` and all work.

```
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(15000);
```